# How to print dropped elements in a stream with OverflowStrategy?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Is there a way to print the dropped elements of a stream when using [OverflowStrategy.dropHead](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/index.html#akka.stream.OverflowStrategy$) or [OverflowStrategy.dropTail](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/index.html#akka.stream.OverflowStrategy$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [akka.stream.impl.ActorRefSourceActor](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/release-2.3-dev/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/ActorRefSourceActor.scala) can be of any help [there are these two](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/release-2.3-dev/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/impl/ActorRefSourceActor.scala#L57-L62) `case`s in `receive`:

```
    case DropHead ⇒
      buffer.dropHead()
      buffer.enqueue(elem)
    case DropTail ⇒
      buffer.dropTail()
      buffer.enqueue(elem)
```

I think it crosses out possibility to have the elements printed out before being dropped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer) Now, that's sad. It means if I want to monitor this kind of things in the stream, I have to do it somehow externally (or, modifying the sources)?